# Error during trigger execution -ORA-04088？

Tags: oracle, triggers

The trigger will work if the update value is out of range of the employee's salary.

Here is my trigger code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_sal_range_12483
  BEFORE UPDATE OF min_salary, max_salary ON cux_jobs_12483
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  v_num NUMBER;
BEGIN

  SELECT e.employee_id
    INTO v_num
    FROM cux_employees_12483 e
   WHERE e.job_id = 'SA_MAN'
     AND e.salary NOT BETWEEN :NEW.min_salary AND :NEW.max_salary;

  IF SQL%ROWCOUNT >= 1 THEN
    raise_application_error(-20901, 'Salary out of range!');
  END IF;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE || SQLERRM);
  WHEN too_many_rows THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE || SQLERRM);
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE || SQLERRM);
    raise_application_error(-20901, 'Salary out of range!');
END;
```

And here is the call:

```
BEGIN
  UPDATE cux_jobs_12483
     SET min_salary = 500, max_salary = 10000
   WHERE job_id = 'SA_MAN';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE || SQLERRM);
END;
```

The error code is:

```
-20901ORA-20901: Salary out of range!
ORA-06512: at "CHECK_SAL_RANGE_12483", line 12
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'CHECK_SAL_RANGE_12483'
```

If i don't add raise_application_error in the EXCEPTION of trigger, the update will success and trigger dosen't work.

Comment: I want the trigger interrupt the update if there have a employee who's salary is out of the new range.

Comment: Seems it does just that. You want to raise an exception if there is invalid input.

Comment: `ORA-04088` is just a consequence of `ORA-06512`, which is a consequence of your unhandled custom `ORA-20901` error.

Comment: The `when others` doesn't handle the consequence ? @ÁlvaroGonzález

Comment: Yes but it seem's not interrupt the `update` if i don't add `raise_application_error` in `exception `. @Rene

Comment: @user6148078. Yes the exception is the way to interupt the update. That's how it works. It is up to the code that executes the update statement to handle the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how exceptions work: if you catch them, they aren't automatically raised to the caller. So don't (go) catch them ;) if that's what you want.

The

```
  IF SQL%ROWCOUNT >= 1 THEN
    raise_application_error(-20901, 'Salary out of range!');
  END IF;
```

Is caught in your trigger, **and interrupts the update**, by your exception block:

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN ...
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE || SQLERRM);
    raise_application_error(-20901, 'Salary out of range!');
END;
```

## But you do something wrong here!

... because you raise your Salary error event if its not linked with the amount! You raise it in any "`OTHERS`" case.

You must remove this thing raising the wrong error in any case, so:

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN no_data_found THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE || SQLERRM);
  WHEN too_many_rows THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE || SQLERRM);
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    dbms_output.put_line(SQLCODE || SQLERRM);
    raise;
END;
```

Comment: The `update` can be interrupt by the exception or the exception just throw the error message? @J. Chomel